# Beginner Drupal question - how to get content to root when installed on /drupal

Tags: drupal

There has got to be an answer to this, but I am a total web developer newbie.  My hosted site has Drupal installed on <site domain>/Drupal.

Everything is fine, but how do I publish the site so that I don't have to go to `domain.com/drupal`?

I want just `domain.com` to work.

Do I have to copy the contents to the root of my www?  I am totally clueless obviously.

EDIT

Note - I also want the URLs in the browser window to drop the drupal path.  So just redirecting to the subdirectory is not desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Here is the drupal site content:

http://drupal.org/node/135206

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the webserver to do that for you.

This is a simple example of a host configuration for Apache2. (This is from Ubuntu, but should be similar to other installations)

```
<VirtualHost *> 
        ServerName example.com 
        ServerAlias example.com *.example.com 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal 
        <Directory /var/www/drupal> 
                Include /etc/apache2/drupal-clean-url.conf 

                Allow from all 
                Options +Includes +Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
                AllowOverride None 
        </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

Among other possibilities, it sounds like you may be hosted on DreamHost.com, or an ISP with a similar setup.  I am hosted on Dreamhost.com, and had a similar problem when getting started.

If this applies to you, you need to mess with your domain settings.
Rather than try to explain it here, I'd refer you to the ISP's tech-support.  They likely have a stock answer for this.

Comment: Yep - it is with godaddy.  I can choose to install it in the root, but I would rather not.  It just seemed more logical to have it in a subdirectory and point to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the webserver make /Drupal the root node, how exactly to do this depends on your webserver but should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

Just copy all of the files and directories in the drupal subdirectory to the one above. i.e. at the same level as the drupal folder. Drupal itself doesn't care where it is. It is the .htaccess file that drives traffic to the correct place within Drupal.

Additionally make sure you try to get clean urls working within Drupal for SEO friendly urls without q=admin e.t.c.  Look at pathauto and token module to help with this aswell, they will give you urls like mysite.com/How_to_run_Drupal for a headline of How to run Drupal.